# How to downgrade laravel version from 8.x to 7.x?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7, laragon

I just started learning laravel from one of the online lessons, but in the tutorial I use laravel 7 while when I install laravel via `laragon`, It automatically installs laravel 8. How can I downgrade laravel 8 to laravel 7 on my `laragon`?

*Laravel 8 version was already installed on my localhost.

Comment: better to create a new one with version 7.* = composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel PROJECT_NAME "7.*"

Comment: Why would you downgrade if I may ask? If you are learning, why not learn the latest version (the differences are not that big )

Comment: I recommend not using laragon or same. Install laravel with composer and run with sail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't use laragon but I searched and I realized that `Laragon` has a file named **sites.conf** Which is located in `{LARAGON_ROOT}\usr\sites.conf` . You can open and change this configuration to your liking such as creating laravel project. Change this line

```
Laravel=composer create-project laravel/laravel %s --prefer-dist
```

to

```
Laravel=composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 projectName
```

I hope this way is useful.

Answer (score -1):

By default, Laragon will download and install the newest version of Laravel.
To downgrade, I think the only way is reinstalling Laravel 7 and running the following command in Laragon:

```
composer create-project...
```

Comment: Looks more like a comment to me.